# Give to the accountant bank statements that show IBAN, SWIFT, sort code, acct #, etc?

Tags: bank-account, security

I've just registered as self-employed and my accountant obviously needs my bank statements, so I can print them out no problem but on top of the first page of each monthly statement are included my bank acct details like IBAN, SWIFT, sort code etc and also on each page of each statement there are also my sort code and acct nr..

The Q is are those details of use for the accountant for the purpose of his job ? Is it safe to give him the statements like that or do I need to erase those parts of the page first ?

Answer (score 5):

If you don’t trust your accountant to keep your financial information confidential, you need a new accountant. If you do trust him to keep your financial information confidential, then it does no harm to give him your complete bank statements.